# fullcalendar eventRender is not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am making a site using fullcalendar. I have a recurring events, and I have a function that exclude the day that I gathered from DB. I made it in eventRender. However, the problem is it works fine in PC, but it doesn't work when I go to website by my phone. 
Here is my eventRender code

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    var Id = event.id;
    var Title = event.title;
    var startDate = new Date(theDate);
    var theDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm");
    var excludedList = <?php echo $json_array; ?>;

    var dowstart = event.dowstart;

    if(typeof dowstart != 'undefined') {
        if(new Date(theDate) < new Date(dowstart)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < excludedList.length ; i++) {
        var excludedTomorrrow = new Date(excludedList[i]["excludedDate"]);
        var endtime = new Date(excludedTomorrrow.getTime() + 30*60000);
        if( new Date(theDate) >= new Date(excludedTomorrrow) && new Date(theDate) < new Date(endtime) && Id == excludedList[i]["id"]  ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the wrong result when I go to website by my phone

[image]
Here is the correct result when I use my PC

[image]

+) further explanation

in the eventRender, I have a canceledDate and newly Booked Date in my DB like this, [DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMGqR.png). Thus, the event that is in canceledDate is not rendered, and newlyBookedDate is rendered in my eventRender. it works fine in PC and also I tried it in android studio emulator, it works fine. However, the problem is when I connect to my website using my iphone, canceledDate is not excluded, but newlyBookedDate are added. I think there is some problem in Date comparison, and that makes events are not excluded.

Comment: `$.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm")` should be `event.start.format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm");`. $.fullCalendar.formatDate has been deprecated ever since fullCalendar 2.0, and may not work reliably. It no longer has any entry in the documentation. You should be using momentJS's format() function to display dates.

Comment: Anyway, the question is difficult to answer for a number of reasons: 1) we can't see your event data or the content of `excludedList`, so we don't know for sure how the code gets to the desired output. Also your description of what the eventRender function is meant to do is very vague - please give an accurate enough description that one of us could completely re-implement the function based on just that description. Don't make us stare at your two screenshots for ages to try and figure it out. "Doesn't work" doesn't really describe the problem, we need to know the exact expectations.

Comment: Lastly "mobile" is not a single platform. So saying it doesn't work "on mobile" is not much use. On which device(s) and browser(s) do you experience this issue? Have you tried using any kind of emulator and/or debugging the device to see if there are errors in the console - this seems like a strong possibility? One (merely speculative) suggestion I can make is that the implementation of the native JS Date and the comparisons can sometimes vary slightly. I'd recommended instead using momentJS objects and their comparison functions as they have got cross-browser compatibility built in.

Comment: See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/ (for accepting strings into momentJS) and http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/ (for functions to compare two dates).

Comment: Please provide a working example. [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/a7mad24/jso51pm6/) you have a basic example to start with. Fork it and add your data/functions

Comment: @ADyson sorry for late. I edited my question. Like you said, I think that the Date and the comparisons have some problems. So, what did you mean in cross-browser compatibility? does native JS does not support the Iphone browser?

Comment: @yongseung "does native JS does not support the Iphone browser"...its more the other way round. It depends how closely the iphone browser's implementation of JavaScript adheres to the the JavaScript specifications. I'm speculating really, since there isn't enough info to answer the question directly, but over a few years of web development I've noticed that different browsers don't always do things the same way. I used to be _much_ worse in the days of IE6, Netscape etc but there can still be differences. A library like momentJS is useful because it will have worked round them.

Comment: @ADyson umm..... ok.. so I changed it to momentJS and it works!! Thank you for giving me such a great information!